# VBA to export selected row values of excel to csv

Tags: excel, vba, export-to-csv

I have a requirement for VBA, wherein, If I select a cell in excel, it will export that entire row values to csv.

I have tried

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

Dim My_filenumber As Integer
Dim logSTR As String

My_filenumber = FreeFile

logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(2, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(3, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(4, "A").Value

Open "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Sample.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

If the range selection can be made dynamic, it can solve the purpose.

Comment: So you plan to use `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)`?  `target.row` gives you the selected row.

Comment: The "Sub" should run as and when it is being called, else it will be difficult to work on the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the code to copy the "values in the entire row where the cell is active" and paste to csv file.

'''

```
Sub xlRangeToCSVFile() 
Dim myWB As Workbook 
Dim rngToSave As Range 
Dim fNum As Integer 
Dim csvVal As String 
Dim i As Integer 
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
csvVal = ""
fNum = FreeFile
Set rngToSave = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":J" & ActiveCell.Row)
Open "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Sample.csv" For Output As #fNum
i = 1
For j = 1 To rngToSave.Columns.Count
csvVal = csvVal & Chr(34) & rngToSave(i, j).Value & Chr(34) & ","
Next
Print #fNum, Left(csvVal, Len(csvVal) - 1)
csvVal = ""
Close #fnum
End Sub
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

### Export Selection Rows to CSV

```vb
Sub ExportRowsToCSV()

    Const FILE_PATH_RIGHT As String = "\Desktop\Sample.csv"
    Const FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A2"
    Const ColDelimiter As String = "," ' or ";"
    Const RowDelimiter As String = vbLf
    
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no visible workbook open
    If Not TypeOf ActiveSheet Is Worksheet Then Exit Sub ' not a worksheet
    If Not TypeOf Selection Is Range Then Exit Sub ' not a range selected
    
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & FILE_PATH_RIGHT
    ' or:
    'FilePath = Environ("OneDrive") & FILE_PATH_RIGHT
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Selection
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = drg.Worksheet
    
    Dim srg As Range
    With ws.UsedRange
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
        Set srg = ws.Range(FIRST_CELL_ADDRESS, lCell)
    End With
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Intersect(srg, drg)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set rg = Intersect(srg, rg.EntireRow)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim dLen As Long: dLen = Len(ColDelimiter)
    
    Dim rString As String
    
    Dim rrg As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For Each rrg In rg.Rows
        For Each cell In rrg.Cells
            rString = rString & CStr(cell.Value) & ColDelimiter
        Next cell
        rString = Left(rString, Len(rString) - dLen) & RowDelimiter
    Next rrg
    rString = Left(rString, Len(rString) - Len(RowDelimiter))
    
    Dim TextFile As Long: TextFile = FreeFile
    
    Open FilePath For Append As #TextFile
        Print #TextFile, rString
    Close #TextFile

    MsgBox "Row(s) exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting.  I will upvote your answer if you will (please) comment the code.  (I'm sure you need 2 more points)